# Google Site Map error in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, xml-sitemap

I've installed google site map on my Umbraco (I installed it in 4.9, 4.8 and 4.7). I followed steps in [this site][1] http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/google-sitemap-for-umbraco-4-%28jespercom%29 . But when I browse mydomain.com/GoogleSiteTree.aspx I get this error

***This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.***

I am unable to find the reason. Anyone knows the answer please help.

Comment: just you try uninstall the package and then install package again, it might work.

Comment: @Ankur: I tried , but same result

Comment: I think it is to do with document type, template or (XLST/Razor) issue, can you attach screen grab of it Document Type Property, Template and (XSLT OR Razor) image so that I can rectify, because I have install on my local machine and it worked fine

Comment: @Ankur:Thanks for your response. Can you please tell me what are the steps after installation? Because I can't find a document type for it. I think I have missed some steps after package installation. I can't find the GoogleSiteTree.aspx page also in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Can you open your masterpage and-or XSLT and make sure there is no whitespace at the top of the file?
You may need to bump up the macro in the masterpage that renders the macro, like so:

```
<%@ Master ... %><asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MyPlaceHolder" runat="server"><umbraco:Macro Alias="GoogleSitemap" runat="server" /></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

This might fix your problem as I've seen similar issues when rendering XML or RSS feeds direct from a macro out to the HTTP response.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I can't find any whitespace at the top of the Master Page or XSLT.